# How to create an add item function for a text rpg inventory?

Tags: c++, function, vector

**inventory**

```
vector<string> inventory;
vector<int> inventoryQ;
```

**item adding function**

```
void addItem(string item, int quantity){
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++){
      if(inventory[i] == item){
        inventoryQ[i] += quantity;
        cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
      } else if(i == inventory.size()){
        inventory.push_back(item);
        inventoryQ.push_back(quantity);
        cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

**example of it in use**

```
user.addItem("Gold", 1);
```

No text is being output into console either.

Comment: Please show us all relevant code. And also, did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you explain how your code for `addItem` is supposed to work? I can see things that are wrong and perhaps could write something more correct, but I doubt you would gain anything from that alone

Comment: it looks like you wanted to implement some kind of find, to see if the item is already in the list, is this correct?

Comment: The loop condition is `i < inventory.size()`, so `i == inventory.size()` in the `else if` can never be true

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting `else if(i == inventory.size())` to be taken when the loop was iterated without finding a match.

Trouble is, inside the loop *this condition will never be true*.

It is only true *after* the loop.

So, move that logic after the loop, and either `return` from within the matching condition, or set a boolean to track what's happened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i` never reaches `inventory.size()`. You could refactor the method to:

```
void addItem(string item, int quantity) {
    // First check if the item already exists
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
        if(inventory[i] == item){
            inventoryQ[i] += quantity;
            cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    // If it doesn't exist, add it to the inventory.
    inventory.push_back(item);
    inventoryQ.push_back(quantity);
    cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void addItem(string item, int quantity){
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++){
      if(inventory[i] == item){
        inventoryQ[i] += quantity;
        cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
      } else if(i == inventory.size()){
        inventory.push_back(item);
        inventoryQ.push_back(quantity);
        cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
      }
    }
}
```

Okay, your loop ends when i reaches inventory.size(), so under what conditions does your else-if happen? Answer: it won't.

What you need to do is return out of the method inside the first if-clause:

```
      if(inventory[i] == item){
        inventoryQ[i] += quantity;
        cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
        return;
      }
```

And then if you make it out the end of the loop without returning, then just do this:

```
        inventory.push_back(item);
        inventoryQ.push_back(quantity);
        cout << "x" << quantity << " " << item << " was added to your inventory." << endl;
```

That code is OUTSIDE the for-loop, because it only happens if you make it to the end of the array without finding the item already in inventory.

Now, think about this... If you don't return-out (or otherwise break from the loop), then you're going to compare EVERY item in inventory against the new item, even once you've found it. This is inefficient. You can stop once you find it.

If you don't like to return from the middle of your method (some people think that's bad design), then you instead need to keep a bool whether you found the item, set it inside the if-clause, and still break from the for-loop, or use the variable as part of the condition:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; !found && i < inventory.size(); i++) {
    if (...) {
        ...
        found = true;
    }
}
```